# ldapwhoami -D vs -U

Tags: authentication, openldap

I have an LDAP user with this schema:

```
dn: uid=portal,ou=Special Accounts,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
sn: portal
cn: portal
uid: portal
```

Can anyone tell me why this would work:

`ldapwhoami -h yorktown -U portal`

but this:

`ldapwhoami -h yorktown -D "uid=portal,ou=Special Accounts,dc=example,dc=com"`

results in

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Invalid credentials (49)
        additional info: SASL(-13): user not found: no secret in database
```

Comment: What's your `sasl-regexp` in slapd.conf (if you have one)? What 
SASL authentication mechanism are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `-D` is for simple authentication and `-U` is only for SASL.  When I do `ldapwhoami -h yorktown -D "uid=portal,ou=Special Accounts,dc=example,dc=com" -x` it works fine.